# How to get length of speech synthesis audio with java?

Tags: java, audio, text-to-speech

I have successfully obtained text-to-speech with Amazon API.
I wrote the returned stream as an mp3 file.
I would like to get length of this mp3 file, I tried to use
mp3agic to get it, but it awalys failed. it reported error as below:
(com.mpatric.mp3agic.InvalidDataException: No mpegs frames found)
I can get length via mp3agic for a real mp3 file (example an mp3 file downloaded on internet)

**I am sure the audio file can be played by player, but it's not a real mp3 file, so How can i get length of speech synthesis audio with java?**

**Below is code for text to speech with amazon API.**

```
 InputStream stream = synthesize(polly, text, voice, OutputFormat.MP3);
            Instant end = Instant.now();
            long cost = Duration.between(start, end).toMillis();
            log.info("text translate to speech cost time: " + cost + " ms");

convertStreamToFile(stream,generatedFilePath);


private  InputStream synthesize(PollyClient polly, String text, Voice voice, OutputFormat format) throws IOException {

        SynthesizeSpeechRequest synthReq = SynthesizeSpeechRequest.builder()
                .text(text)
                .voiceId(voice.id())
                .outputFormat(format)
                .build();

        ResponseInputStream<SynthesizeSpeechResponse> synthRes = polly.synthesizeSpeech(synthReq);
        return synthRes;
    }

    private void convertStreamToFile(InputStream stream,String filePath) {

        Converter conv = new Converter();
        Converter.ProgressListener listener =
                new Converter.PrintWriterProgressListener(
                        new PrintWriter(System.out, true), 0);


        Decoder.Params decoderParams = new Decoder.Params();

        try
        {
            conv.convert(stream,filePath, listener, decoderParams);
            long cost = Duration.between(start, end).toMillis();
            log.info("convert successful,convert cost time:,{} ms", cost);
        }
        catch (JavaLayerException ex)
        {
            log.error("convertStreamToFile for textToSpeech error,{}", ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```